# jquery add table row with json data in dropdowns

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a web form with a table that the user can add additional rows to. The first row of the table consists of dependent dropdowns. The dropdowns are populated with json data from a referenced file. The code that I am using for it is as follows:

```
//the add row function
$(function(){
var newgroup = $('<tr>').addClass('rec-rows');
$('#addRow').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
$('.rec-rows').first().clone().appendTo(newgroup).appendTo('#details');     }); 

});

//onChange function
$(".rec-rows #section").live('change',function(){


var sSec =$(this).parent().find('#section').val();  

$("#divParts").hide();
$("#divDesc").hide(); 
$("#divGroup").hide(); 
if(sSec=="select") {
$("#divCategory").hide();
} else {
$.getJSON("static/site_category.json",  function(json) {
var catJson = json[sSec];
var options = "<option value=\"select\">Select Area Type</option>";
for(i=0;i<catJson.length;i++) {
options +="<option value=\""+catJson[i].ky+"\">"+catJson[i].val+"</option>"
}
```

Theoretically, a new row is added and the onChange code I pasted will work for each additional row. However, the results are not like that at all. Instead, when the row is added and the user makes a selection on the new row, the values are updated in the first row.The first part of the table looks like this:

```
<td width="" align="left"> 
<div>
<select id="section" name="section" style="margin-top:15px;"> 
<option value="select">Select Area</option> 
<option value="a">a</option> 
<option value="b">b</option> 
<option value="c">c</option> 
</select> 
</div> 
</td>
```

I appreciate any help to get this code working as desired - which would be a simple added row where the dropdown selections only update on the row that they are found on. Thank you.

Comment: I did find this post that might answer what I need to do to get the desired results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008316/clone-div-and-rename-element-ids-incrementally But I am not sure how to incorporate it into existing code? Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

you can look at my answer here of how to add a row dynamically to the start of a table:

[How can I dynamically generate a table row with it's tds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184674/how-can-i-dynamically-generate-a-table-row-with-its-tds/5185219#5185219)

It might help you here.

or i also i see a problem.

change $("#section").change(

to:

```
$("#section").live('change',...
```

that could be why the new dropdowns are not working

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, it did not work as the dropdown selects did not work on the added rows. :( I have tried a similar solution where instead of cloning I appended the data like in your solution above.

Comment: can you provide the html of the 1st part of the table above so i can try to see totally what you are doing?

Comment: Okay, I have added the html of the first part of the table. Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide to help with a solution.

Comment: Nope, did not work. Let me update my code above so you can see what I have been trying the last hour...

Comment: I have edited my question above. I got the modifications from this post that seems to be attempting what I am, except I cannot get it to work with my onChange function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008316/clone-div-and-rename-element-ids-incrementally

Comment: why are you doing this? var sSec =$(this).parent().find('#section').val();

Comment: i was experimenting to see if either parent or closest would cause the correct dropdowns to be populated. It only produced the same results I was already getting.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution! I was advised to declare the parent such as in the following context:

```
$(".section").change( function () {
var sSec =$(this).val();  
context = $(this).parents("tr");
if(sSec=="select") {
$("#divCategory", context).hide();
} else {
$.getJSON("static/site_category.json",  function(json) {
var catJson = json[sSec];
var options = "<option value=\"select\">Select Area Type</option>";
for(i=0;i<catJson.length;i++) {
options +="<option value=\""+catJson[i].ky+"\">"+catJson[i].val+"</option>"
```

Now for every "add row" click, a row gets added and the dropdowns are changed upon user selection for that row and only that row.